# Scientific explanation why word2vec models perform poorly on small data

Tags: word2vec, gensim

I would like to know if there is any scientific explanation why word2vec models like CBOW perform poorly on small data. Here's what I tested;

```
data=[[context1], [context2], [context3]......[contextn]]

model=trained word2vec model

model.most_similar('word')
output=[word not in even in top-10]
```

I retrained the model with 10 times the dataset.

```
model.most_similar(word)
output=[word in the 10 most similar words]
```

Is there any scientific reason for the improvement in performance as the data size increased other than the increase in the word count with increase in data?

Answer (score 5):

Words start word2vec-training in random places, and Word2Vec can only "deduce" that a pair of words are alike if it sees many instructive examples that, gradually over all training, nudge those words into similar positions. It can only arrange many, many words so that all those pairwise similarities are simultaneously upheld if it gets many, many, many varied examples and thus many, many, many chances to incrementally nudge them all into better places.

If you have a tiny dataset:

(1) There might be no, or very few, examples where the desired-to-be-alike words are in similar nearby-word contexts. With *no* examples where there are shared nearby-words, there's little basis for nudging the pair to the same place – the internal Word2Vec task, of predicting nearby words, doesn't *need* them to be near each other, if they're each predicting completely different words. But even with a *few* examples, there are problems, like...

(2) Words need to move *a lot* from their original random positions, to eventually reach the useful 'constellation' you get form a successful word2vec session. If a word only appears in your dataset 10 times, and you train over the dataset 10 iterations, that word gets just 100 CBOW nudges. If instead the word happens 1000 times, then 10 training iterations give it 10,000 CBOW updates – a much better chance to move from an initially-arbitrary location to a useful location. As a result, you can *sometimes* squeeze slightly-better results from smaller datasets by increasing your training-iterations. That somewhat simulates a larger corpus. But there's still not real variety in those repeated contexts, so you still have the problem of...

(3) Smaller datasets, with largish-models (lots of 'free parameters', like the independent coordinates of every context-word and predicted target-word), give rise to 'overfitting'. That is, they can become really good at the training task, essentially by 'memorizing' the idiosyncracies of the data, and not achieve the sort of compression/generalization that's usually wanted to be able to apply the results to novel varied data. For example, within a tiny corpus, with lots of internal parameters, maybe 'happy' and 'ecstatic' don't *need* to be near each other - their contexts only overlap a little, and there's lots of 'space' inside the model to put them in totally different places but still do well predicting their neighboring words. You can sometimes squeeze whatever generalization is possible by *shrinking the model*, for example making the vector `size` parameter much smaller, when the dataset is tiny. Then it's still forced to make use of whatever (few) context-similarities that exist.

But the essence of Word2Vec is using bulk data, and bulk training, to force the discovery of generalizable patterns – so tricks to stretch small-corpuses into something that just-barely-works aren't taking advantage of it, in the way it is strongest.

Comment: thank you so much for this very detailed explanation; very clear and relevant.